# Reduce Array of objects and update initialized counters using JavaScrip

Tags: javascript

Having issues with Reduce function, for some reason, I don't understand it as I want it to be, therefore I am adding this post.
I have an Array of Object, for example:

```
const arr = [{address: 'abc.com', class: 'a'}, {address: 'bcd.com', class: 'b'}, 
{address: 'efg.com', class: 'a'}]
```

Now, I want to initialize 2 counters that will be increased by the value of the 'class'.
For example:

```
counterA=2, counterB=1.
```

I was able to handle it by using `SumBy` of lodash and also by `filter()` but I want to do this using reduce.

```
  const aCount = arr.filter(
  item => item.class === 'a').length;
```

I would like to use the reduce function for that.
Help please.

Comment: Why the instance on `reduce`? The filter you have is perfect. Just run one for 'b' and you're done.

Comment: I want to do it by one call and not run it by 2 different calls - that was my first approach by I want to optimize it.

Comment: Do you mean optimize for speed, readability, complexity factor or something else?

Comment: There you go, MrPolywhirl just gave you your optimized `reduce`! LOL. So much better than two simple calls to `.filter()`. This is probably why you're struggling to optimize past simplicity. More complex code is not necessary an optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` like this :

```js
const arr = [{
    address: 'abc.com',
    class: 'a'
  }, {
    address: 'bcd.com',
    class: 'b'
  },
  {
    address: 'efg.com',
    class: 'a'
  }
]

const [counterA, counterB] = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, {
  class: c
}) => ({
  ...acc,
  [c]: acc[c] + 1 || 1
}), {}));

console.log(`counterA: ${counterA} and counterB: ${counterB}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = [{address: 'abc.com', class: 'a'}, {address: 'bcd.com', class: 'b'}, 
{address: 'efg.com', class: 'a'}]

const res = arr.reduce((a,b) => {
  let counterA = a.counterA || 0
  let counterB = a.counterB || 0
  if(a.class === 'a') counterA++
  if(b.class === 'a') counterA++
  if(a.class === 'b') counterB++
  if(b.class === 'b') counterB++
  return {counterA, counterB}
})

console.log(res)
```

at `reducer` at the first run `a` in the fist element of `arr` and `b` is the second element of `arr`. in other runs `a` is result of previous run and `b` in new element of `arr`.

in this code i try to get previous `counterA` and `counterB` if exists in `a` (2nd run and other) and get class from both `a` and `b` (`a` for fist run and `b` for other runs) and if content of class is `'a'` add one to `counterA` and do the same for `'b'` and create an object and return it to use in another runs.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a frequency map.

Simply reduce the items into an object, where the key is the `class` and the value is the occurrence.

```js
const arr = [
  { address: 'abc.com', class: 'a' },
  { address: 'bcd.com', class: 'b' }, 
  { address: 'efg.com', class: 'a' }
];

const counter = arr.reduce((acc, { class: cls }) => ({
  ...acc,
  [cls]: (acc[cls] ?? 0) + 1
}), {});

console.log(counter);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

#### Notes

- I [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `class` field from each object in the reducer function. Since `class` is a reserved word, I had to rename it to `cls`.
- I used [nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to get the current value of the object's field or zero then I incremented and set the new value.